# Failed image upload again and again

Tags: laravel-6

Image upload fails when using laravel 6.

> Controller

```
 public function saveProduct(Request $request){
       /*image  upload  process */
     $productimage = $request->file('image');
       $imageName =  $productimage->getClientOriginalName();
       $directory = 'Product-image/';
       $imageUrl = $directory.$imageName;
       $productimage->move($directory,$imageName);

       $product= new Product();
       $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
       $product->brand_id = $request->brand_id;
       $product->product_price = $request->product_price;
       $product->product_quantity = $request->product_quantity;
       $product->shortdescription = $request->shortdescription;
       $product->longdescription = $request->longdescription;
       $product->image = $imageUrl;
       $product->public_status = $request->public_status;
       $product->save();
       return redirect('/product/add')->with('message','Prodect added saved  successfully');
```

> Migration

```
 Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->integer('brand_id');
            $table->float('product_price',8,2);
            $table->integer('product_quantity');
            $table->text('shortdescription');
            $table->text('longdescription');
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('public_status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

> Routes

```
Route::get('/product/add', 'ProductController@index')->name('addproduct'); Route::post('/product/new', 'ProductController@saveProduct')->name('newproduct'); Route::get('/product/manage', 'ProductController@manageProduct')->name('manageproduct');
```

> Blade

```
<h3 class="text-center text-success">{{Session::get('message')}}</h3>
                <form action="{{route('newproduct')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                    @csrf
```

Comment: Does increasing size of post_max_size and upload_max_file ? resolved your query ?

Comment: What is the problem ? Is not storing in database or not save it into the desired folder ?

Comment: If your problem is resolved please mark as resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Please revert back is this resolved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Following will resolve you're the query, By default, the maximum upload file size for PHP scripts is set to 128 megabytes. However, you may want to change these limits. For example, you can set a lower limit to prevent users from uploading large files to your site. To do this, change the upload_max_filesize and post_max_size directives in your php.ini file.

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 21M
```

To verify the current value of the **upload_max_filesize** directive and other directives, you can use the **phpinfo()** function.

You can also do this same by mentioning in you ***.htaccess*** file, if you just want to change these values for your project.

```
// Replace xx with the maximum upload file size that you want to set
php_value upload_max_filesize xxM
// Replace xx with the maximum HTTP POST file size that you want to set
php_value post_max_size xxM
```